# What are all possible uses for Expecto Patronum?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

In the Harry Potter books and films, we saw that Expecto Patronum is mainly used for tackling Dementors and Lethifolds. But what (if any) are ***other*** things that Expecto Patronum can be used for?

In-universe references only, please.

Comment: The answer must be supported by facts from the books, and (of course) the facts must have citation. The answer needs to be plausible, and not far-fetched (I wont accept "Well, this sorta kinda might be true, but probably not.")

Comment: There is another use: the Order of the Phoenix uses them to send messages. I'm currently combing for a quote, and then I'll post an answer

Comment: Wizard Sexting is one use

Comment: Harry could use it to remind himself of his father, since [they both have the same Patronus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_Potter_I#cite_note-accio-quote.org-2)...

Comment: Makes me think of the [HPMOR chapter](http://hpmor.com/chapter/16) with the DADA professor asking Harry "Mr. Potter, all things have their accustomed uses. Give me ten unaccustomed uses of objects in this room for combat!" -- It's kind of a wide open list -- would it be accurate to take your "In-universe references only, please." to mean things that have been show, discussed or referenced in the canon material?  Otherwise this becomes very, very broad...

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one covered pretty much all the bases. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 25):

Aside from being the primary way of protecting yourself from Dementors (and Lethifolds), the patronus charm appears to have at least two other canon uses, as well as several 
theoretical ones

### Communication

On several occasions we see Patronus charm being used to [communicate over long distances](http://web.archive.org/web/20120208051452/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=99) in a way that can't be easily intercepted, for example in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows:

> *Harry did not know where to begin, but it did not matter. At that moment, something large and silver came falling through the canopy
>   over the dance floor. Graceful and gleaming, the lynx landed lightly
>   in the middle of the astonished dancers. Heads turned, as those
>   nearest it froze, absurdly, in mid-dance. Then the Patronus’s mouth
>   opened wide and it spoke in the loud, deep, slow voice of Kingsley
>   Shacklebolt.*
>
> *‘The Ministry has fallen. Scrimgeour is dead. They are coming.’*

---

### As a (secret) guide

In HP and the Deathly Hallows Snape uses his Patronus to guide Harry without revealing himself:

> *And then the source of the light stepped out from behind an oak. It
>   was a silver-white doe, moon-bright and dazzling, picking her way over
>   the ground, still silent, and leaving no hoof prints in the fine
>   powdering of snow. She stepped towards him, her beautiful head with
>   its wide, long-lashed eyes held high.*
>
> *Harry stared at the creature, filled with wonder, not at her
>   strangeness, but at her inexplicable familiarity. He felt that he had
>   been waiting for her to come, but that he had forgotten, until this
>   moment, that they had arranged to meet. His impulse to shout for
>   Hermione, which had been so strong a moment ago, had gone. He knew, he
>   would have staked his life on it, that she had come for him, and him
>   alone.*
>   ...
>   *At last, she came to a halt. She turned her beautiful head towards him once more, and he broke into a run, a question burning in him, but as he opened his lips to ask it, she vanished.*

---

And off the top of my head

- **Since the Patronus charm [can't be cast by a true Death Eater](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/why-could-dolores-umbridge-conjure-a-patronus), you could theoretically use it as way of confirming that someone isn't one.**
- According to [Pottermore](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Patronus_Charm), Remus Lupin is afraid to cast a Patronus as he...

> *...felt afraid that his corporeal Patronus gives too much away.*

So, presumably you could use this **as a way of determining whether someone is or isn't a werewolf**

- According to Pottermore, **the ability to effortlessly produce a patronus was historically used as a method for selecting wizards to serve or lead the Wizarding world:**

> *...those able to produce corporeal Patronuses were often elected to high
>   office within the Wizengamot and Ministry of Magic*

- **You could also use it as a night-light.**

> *He jumped to his feet, his voice frozen in his throat, and raised
>   Hermione’s wand. **He screwed up his eyes as the light became blinding,**
>   the trees in front of it pitch black in silhouette, and still the
>   thing came closer.*

Comment: as a guard? Like Umbridge does it HP and the DH

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may be possible to use a Patronus to fight whatever potion Dumbledore drank in book 6. For Harry, the Dementors bring up his worst memories, and that potion that Dumbledore drank made him relive the death of Ariana, his worst memory. so maybe a Patronus would help to ease or erase the effects of that potion.

> "the Dementor will feed on you long enough to reduce you to something like itself... soulless and evil. You'll be left with nothing but the worst experiences of your life."

Comment: do you have any citations for "and that potion that Dumbledore drank made him relive the death of Ariana, his worst memory"?

Comment: do patronuses bring happy memories to others? I thought it only is produced from happy memories and acts as kind of a short circuit to the dementor's "drain" which i imagine would cause the dementor pain