# Can a Patronus only be used on a dementor? Can a Patronus be used to attack somebody or to drive them away?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

Patronuses are commonly used against Dementors but can they attack someone or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all possible uses for Expecto Patronum?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87479/31394)

Comment: Wait, you would use "happy memory turned into cute magical ghost animal" to attack somebody?! Definitively a Slytherin thing to do.

Comment: @jo1storm I am a Slytherin

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Yes it does! Thankyou!