# In Deathly Hallows, how did Dolores Umbridge manage to conjure a Patronus while wearing the locket when Harry wasn't able to?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, patronus-charm

**Note: This is NOT a question asking why Umbridge can cast a Patronus**

When Harry wears the locket he is unable to cast a Patronus, why can Umbridge cast a Patronus while wearing a Horcrux, when it was supposed to drain the wearer of energy like Harry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why could Dolores Umbridge conjure a Patronus?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/why-could-dolores-umbridge-conjure-a-patronus) (same quote about the locket in the accepted answer)

Comment: Note that for a duplicate the questions don't have to be identical, just that the other question's *answer* also answers this question, which it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JK has answered this directly](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/07/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript/):

> **James Farrell:** How did Umbridge manage to conjure a patronus while
> wearing the locket, when Harry wasn't able to?
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** Because she is a very nasty piece of work. She has an
> affinity for this horrible object, which would help rather than hinder
> her.

Comment: I'm actually surprised James Farrell's question is a verbatim copy of the question in the original post.

Comment: Found your burner account, James

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up