# In the “Spinner’s End” chapter in Half-Blood Prince, how does Bellatrix miss this?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

When Snape is answering Bellatrix’s questions (which also serve as a convenient plot device to explain why Voldemort trusts Snape), he says this about how much Dumbledore trusts him:

> “Not quite,” said Snape calmly. “He wouldn’t give me the Defense Against the Dark Arts job, you know. Seemed to think it might, ah, bring about a relapse… tempt me into my old ways.”

So basically, he’s saying, that Dumbledore thinks letting Snape *teach* DADA would revert him back to a DE, but he doesn't think ***sending Snape back to Voldemort as a spy*** would as well?

Am I the only person who thinks that Bellatrix not immediately bringing this up is uncharacteristic of her?

Comment: I think Dumbledore didn't let Snape teach DADA coz Snape is already very good in potions (too good...) and he also didn't want Snape to get hurt & leave the school when he already has plans for him. Snape can't tell this truth to Bellatrix, so he lied. And as for sending Snape back to Voldemort as a spy Nobody knew this truth except Dumbledore and Snape! Bellatrix can't think about something that she didn't knew in the first place.

Comment: How was I supposed to know Dumbledore sent Snape back to spy on the Dark Lord, instead of him willingly returning to serve the Dark Lord? I think I questioned him quite well with what I knew at the time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bellatrix and the Death Eaters were convinced it was *the other way around*. That he was spying on Dumbledore for Voldemort. And as [the DADA job was cursed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40776/how-does-the-curse-in-dada-works), there is no reason either party would want their spy in the position. As for the exchange, it is a lie. Sometimes [Snape has to lie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17009/did-voldemort-know-when-he-was-being-lied-to-by-snape) to protect his [cover](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/if-it-wasnt-for-his-love-for-lily-would-snape-have-a-patronus).

Comment: "[I'm a potions master and a double agent, duh](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsYWT5Q_R_w)"

Comment: This doesn't seem to really address the question. Why would Dumbledore let Snape pretend to be a Death Eater if he wouldn't even let him teach Defense Against the Dark Arts?

Comment: I *did* address that. It was cursed. (DADA = Defense Against the Dark Arts.)